# How to change the exporting file's column names

Tags: django-import-export

The project I'm working on requires specific column names. Like the current export file has 'Surname' and 'First Name' but I need them to be 'lastname' and 'firstname', respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a resource which is a subclass of [`ModelResource`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#modelresource) and override the `get_export_headers()` method:

```py
class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def get_export_headers(self):
        headers = super().get_export_headers()
        for i, h in enumerate(headers):
            if h == 'Surname':
                headers[i] = "lastname"
            if h == 'First Name':
                headers[i] = "firstname"
        return headers

    class Meta:
        model = Book
```